# PHP giving 500 internal server error on new server

Tags: php, cgi, phpinfo, suphp

I am trying to run a simple PHP script which displays phpinfo() but I am getting 500 internal server error. What could be the reason? Is it because PHP handler is set to suPHP and I shall change it to DSO or CGI?

Thanks

Comment: The reason should be seen in the server's error log.

Comment: Please tell me where I can see that log? I have root access to server.

Comment: this question should be asked from server admin.

Comment: But there must be a default path where log files are saved?

Comment: no, there isn't

Comment: Look around /var/log/httpd, as that's a common log path for Apache. I recommend you ask this question on ServerFault.com; it is a system administration question not a programming question.